# Why Unity script is overwriting other game objects data on which it is attached to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to show different documents to the player when it comes near the pages. I have two pages, both of them are colliders which have triggers, they are using the same script, but with different game objects in the inspector (for showing different documents). A text box would pop up beforehand, which tells the player to enter space key in order to view the document. If the player comes near the Page 1, the 'Image panel' should pop up. If the player comes near the Page 2, the 'Test panel' should pop up. After viewing the document, that page should be destroyed.

[image]

The above image is for 'Page 1'

[image]

The above image is for 'Page 2'

However when the player comes near the Page 1, 'TEST panel' always pop up instead of 'Image Panel' and BOTH of the pages get destroyed afterwards. 'TEST panel' is showing because Page 2's script has overwritten the Page 1's script in a sense, I believe. I am really confused in this matter, I am a beginner at Unity, here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
 public class ViewDocument : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject theText;
     public GameObject theDocument;
     public static bool viewDocument;
     public static bool documentOpened;
 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.tag == "Player")
     {
         theText.SetActive(true);
         viewDocument = true;
     }
 }
 private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
 {
     theText.SetActive(false);
 }
 private void showDocument()
 {
     theText.SetActive(false);
     Debug.Log("Now showing " + theDocument.name); //shows 'Test Panel' in Log, even when 'Image panel' is selected in the inspector for Page 1
     theDocument.SetActive(true);
     documentOpened = true;
     Time.timeScale = 0f;
 }
 private void closeDocument()
 {
     Time.timeScale = 1f;
     theDocument.SetActive(false);
     Destroy(gameObject);
 }
 private void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && viewDocument == true)
     {
         Debug.Log("Before show doc :" + documentOpened.ToString());
         showDocument();
         viewDocument = false;
         Debug.Log("After show doc :"+ documentOpened.ToString());
     }
     else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && documentOpened == true)
     {
         closeDocument();
         Debug.Log("Document closed!");
     }
 }
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unity calls your `Update()` method  sixty times per second (the frame rate).  Do you want that code to execute sixty times per second while the key is pressed, or do you need to put in some logic so that it only gets called once when the key is pressed?

Comment: Note that there are better ways to hook up buttons and keypresses in Unity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I've noticed that the key press should not be in the Update method, but if I place it in the OnTriggerEnter method, the document doesn't pop up at all.

Comment: A `static` variable is shared on all objects of that type. Do you really want those variables to change on *all* of the objects?

Comment: Basically, what I think you're going to want to do is set a flag on keydown, so that your can ignore subsequent Update() calls.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, `GetKeyDown` is only called the frame a key is pressed. This code will already only run once per key press

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you so much! It was actually the ```static``` bool variables which were causing this problem. After removing removing it, the game is working just fine! You're a life saver, can't believe I spent a whole day because of this minor mistake.